# PHP `mail()` problem

Tags: php, email

> > **Related, possible duplicate**: [PHP mail stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892409/php-mail-problem)

Hello;

I have a site hosted on GoDaddy, that processes several news web sites and emails a summary of articles. It has been working fine, until two days ago when I stopped receiving emails. `mail()` returns **true**, and when sending basic text emails I receive them, only HTML I can't receive! Any idea about the cause or how to troubleshoot this issue?

Thanks

---

Update:
This is the code I use (PHP):

`$headers = 'From: Aggregator Daemon' . "\r\n";`

`$headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";`

`$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1252' . "\r\n";`

`$mailres=mail("dummy@nowhere.com","GN Aggregator  - $today Bulletin",$ebody,$headers);`

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by can't receive, do they not arrive or do they arrive broken?

Comment: Check your spam filter and check if GoDaddy has new policies prohibiting you from sending HTML emails.

Comment: @Pekka: I can't receive them in my POP client

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend, use something like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) when dealing with sending emails. It handles all of the headers etc quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that there is something wonky in the headers, particularly the content-type or the encoding.

That being said, something could have changed on the GoDaddy server or one of the MTA's which is causing your email to be rejected for some reason.

There's not really a way to tell without seeing some code.

Also, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892409/php-mail-problem) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a Return-Path header so you receive bounced e-mails. This can not be set in the "additional headers" parameter, but in the "additional parameters" parameter to the [mail](http://php.net/mail) function. On a Linux hosting account you do like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $ebody, $headers, '-f bounceaddress@example.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). I use it in my scripts it's easy in implementing and it works properly. It's also used by WordPress.