# Why is this script not working? (not getting error, simply posts script and looks like it works)

Tags: php, html, contacts

Below is a contact us script in php, when I click submit at www.mydomain.com.au/contact.html it looks as though it works because I end up at ww.mydomain.com.au/thanks.html.
However the specified email account is not receiving contact emails.

Here is the code for the contact us script found at includes/contact_mail.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['enter']) && $_POST['enter']==1)
{
    $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
    $to="name@domains.com";
    $subject='Contact Us Details';
    $message="<style>

                    .textstyle{

                    font-family:Tahoma;

                    font-size:11px;

                    color:#156E00;

                    text-align:left;

                    margin-left:10px;

                    text-decoration:none;
                    }

                    </style>";

        $message.="<table width=400 border=0>

                    <tr><td class=textstyle>First Name:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['fname']."</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class=textstyle>Last Name:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['lname']."</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class=textstyle>E-mail:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class=textstyle>Phone Number:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['tel']."</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class=textstyle>Comments:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['que']."</td></tr>
                    </table>";
        $mail_from = "From:".$_POST['email'];
        $mail_from .="\r\nContent-type: text/html";
        @mail($to,$subject,$message,$mail_from);
    header("location: ../thankyou.html");   
    exit();
}

?>
```

Here is the code at ww.mydomain.com.au/contact.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Macromedia Dreamweaver CS3" />
<meta name="author" content="Relyon security" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Camera Surveillance,Spy Cameras,Remote Viewing,Audio recording,Relyon security" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="EXPIRES" content="-1" />
<title>Relyon Security: About Relyon Security</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css" />
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function fullcheck()
{
  var str=document.contact.email.value;
//alert(str);


     if (document.contact.fname.value=="")
        {
           alert ("Blank space not allowed. Please type your First Name.");
           document.contact.fname.select(); 
           return false;
        } 

        if (document.contact.lname.value=="")
        {
           alert ("Blank space not allowed. Please type your Last Name.");
           document.contact.lname.select(); 
           return false;
        }  


        if ((document.contact.email.value).indexOf(" ")>=0)
        {
        alert ("Blank space not allowed inside email!");
        document.contact.email.select();
        return false;
        }

        if (document.contact.email.value.indexOf("@",1) == -1)
        {
            alert("Invalid E-Mail address");
            document.contact.email.focus();
            document.contact.email.select();
            return(false);
        }
        if (document.contact.email.value.indexOf("@") == 0)
        {
            alert("Invalid E-Mail address");
            document.contact.email.focus();
            document.contact.email.select();
            return(false);
        }
        if (document.contact.email.value.indexOf(".",5) == -1)
        {
            alert("Invalid E-Mail address");
            document.contact.email.focus();
            document.contact.email.select();
            return(false);
        }
        if (document.contact.email.value.indexOf(".") == 0)
        {
            alert("Invalid E-Mail address");
            document.contact.email.focus();
            document.contact.email.select();
            return(false);
        }

        if ((document.contact.email.value.lastIndexOf(".")) -(document.contact.email.value.indexOf("@"))<4 )
        {

            alert("Invalid E-Mail address");
            document.contact.email.focus();
            document.contact.email.select();
            return(false);
        }
        if (document.contact.tel.value=="")
        {
           alert ("Blank space not allowed. Please type your Telephone Number.");
           document.contact.tel.select(); 
           return false;
        }

        if (document.contact.que.value=="")
        {
           alert ("Blank space not allowed. Please enter your question or comment.");
           document.contact.que.select(); 
           return false;
        }

}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left" width="110" height="186"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
<td width="780" rowspan="2" align="center" valign="top">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
  <tr>
    <td height="161" valign="top"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left" class="btn">
        <table width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
  <tr>
    <td width="10" valign="top"><img src="images/btn-left.jpg" alt="" width="10" height="49" /></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">
        <table width="760" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="154" align="center" valign="top"><a href="index.html" class="navg_home">Home Page</a></td>
    <td width="180" align="center" valign="top"><a href="our_services.html" class="navg_home">Our Services</a></td>
    <td width="244" align="center" valign="top"><a href="about.html" class="navg_about">About relyon security</a></td>
    <td width="182" align="center" valign="top"><span class="navg_contact_activated">Contact Us</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
    <td width="10" valign="top" align="right"><img src="images/btn-right.jpg" alt="" width="10" height="49" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" height="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="10"><img src="images/left-bot.jpg" alt="" width="10" height="42" /></td>
    <td class="shadow"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/rgh-bot.jpg" alt="" width="10" height="42" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td>
<td valign="top" align="left" width="110"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top" align="left" width="110" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="66"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
<td valign="top" align="left" width="110" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="white">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" class="inner_text"><span class="head-blue">Contact Us</span><br /><br />
      Email address: <a href="mailto:relyonsecurity@live.com.au" class="more">relyonsecurity@live.com.au</a>
      <br />

  Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0422 663 489<br />
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="1000" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="blue">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><table width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
    <form name="contact" method="post" action="includes/contact_mail.php" onsubmit="return fullcheck()">        

        <table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3" >

                <tr>
                  <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
                  <td height="30" colspan="2" align="left" valign="middle"><span class="mandatory">*</span>Required fields</td>
                </tr>


                   <tr>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="22%" class="form_text"><span class="mandatory">*</span>First Name :</td>
            <td width="71%"><input name="fname" type="text"  id="fname" size="35" class="inputbox"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
                   <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="22%" class="form_text"><span class="mandatory">*</span>Last Name :</td>
            <td width="71%"><input name="lname" type="text"  id="lname" size="35" class="inputbox"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="form_text"><span class="mandatory">*</span>Email Address :</td>
            <td><input name="email" type="text"  class="inputbox" id="email" size="35"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="7%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="form_text"><span class="mandatory">*</span>Telephone Number:</td>
            <td><input name="tel" type="text"  class="inputbox" id="tel" size="35"></td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="form_text"><span class="mandatory">*</span>Please enter your question or comment :</td>
            <td><textarea name="que" cols="33" rows="8" id="que" class="inputbox"></textarea></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" height="5" valign="top"><input name="enter" type="hidden" value="1" /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="form_text">&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="inputbox">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset" class="inputbox"></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="3" height="30" valign="top"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
<table width="780" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="footer" height="41">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="12" height="8"><img src="images/foo-l-top.gif" alt="" width="12" height="8" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
    <td align="right" valign="top" width="9" height="8"><img src="images/foo-r-top.gif" alt="" width="9" height="8" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
    <td align="center" valign="middle">&copy;2009 Relyon Security.com All Rights Reserved</td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom" height="8"><img src="images/foo-l-bot.gif" alt="" width="12" height="8" /></td>
    <td><img src="images/spacer.gif" alt="" /></td>
    <td valign="bottom"><img src="images/foo-r-bot.gif" alt="" width="9" height="8" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Second attempt at script?

```
    <?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL)

if(isset($_POST['enter']) && $_POST['enter']==1)
    {
        $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['email'];
        $to="name@domains.com";
        $subject='Contact Us Details';
        $message="<style>

                        .textstyle{

                        font-family:Tahoma;

                        font-size:11px;

                        color:#156E00;

                        text-align:left;

                        margin-left:10px;

                        text-decoration:none;
                        }

                        </style>";

            $message.="<table width=400 border=0>

                        <tr><td class=textstyle>First Name:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['fname']."</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class=textstyle>Last Name:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['lname']."</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class=textstyle>E-mail:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['email']."</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class=textstyle>Phone Number:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['tel']."</td></tr>
                        <tr><td class=textstyle>Comments:  </td> <td class=textstyle>".$_POST['que']."</td></tr>
                        </table>";
            $mail_from = "From:".$_POST['email'];
            $mail_from .="\r\nContent-type: text/html";
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$mail_from);
       // header("location: ../thankyou.html");   
        exit();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: You've suppressed the `mail()` function. Is it throwing any errors?

Comment: @JohnP no errors, feel free to submit your self and see http://www.relyonsecurity.com.au/contact.html

Comment: Don't use `@function()`, just... just DON'T!

Comment: This is way too much code, and a much too broad debugging issue to be dealt with in a SO question. Please isolate the source of the problem first. If `mail()` works but no mail is received, there are other SO questions that can help on that, for example this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892409

Comment: @Pekka I only have basic php understanding, the writer of the website is no longer contactable. This was my only option :)

what is SO?

Comment: SO = StackOverflow The purpose of SO is to provide users with a platform to address numerous subject matter experts and hopefully garner some insight into their problem. @user594777, what have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the top of the script, remove `@` from `mail()` call and comment string with `header()` and THEN look for errors

Comment: @Emmerman I have uploaded the code edited with your suggestions apart from "comment string with header()" how/where does this go? plese specify for a newb

Comment: `header("location: ../thankyou.html");` replace with `// header("location: ../thankyou.html");`

Comment: @Emmerman, code above updated.
Here is the error I received
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/admin/domains/relyonsecurity.com.au/public_html/includes/contact_mail.php on line 4

Comment: You should probably pay someone to fix this since you don't seem to know any programming at all...

Comment: @Emmerman I have added;, still not receiving any emails.
@vichle thats for being negative :)

Comment: @Emmerman No errors at all, feel free to submit here http://www.relyonsecurity.com.au/contact.html

Comment: then maybe your mail server is down

Comment: @user this is what I mean by "too broad". I mean no offense and I'll be happy for you if someone here manages to solve this or give you some pointers, but there are so many variables here that *could* be wrong that it's going to be an hour-long debugging session to find out what it is. It could be more productive to look for a freelancer in your area who can take a look.