# PHP mail() not working with a specific suffix

Tags: php, email

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP mail stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892409/php-mail-stopped-working)

I'm using PHP `mail()` function to send a Contact Us form.
This works for all the emails that I've tried but the ones with the customer's company suffix:`[something]@3gdirectpay.com`. 
The function returns `true`, but he doesn't get anything, even after checking the spam.

The code:

```
<?php

$email="You have recieved a new message from a customer: \r\n \r\n";
if (isset($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (isset($value) && $value!='' && $key[0]!='x' && $key!='mf_mail' && $key!=='mf_text') {
            $email.=$_POST['x' . $key] . $value . "<br>";
        }
        else if ($key=='mf_text') {
            $text = "Message: " . $value;
        }
}
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";   
$email.= $text;
$to = "info@3gdirectpay.com, eran@3gdirectpay.com";
$from = $_POST['mf_mail'];
$subject = "New message from a customer";
mail($to,$subject,$email,$headers);



    }

header("Location:http://www.3gdirectpay.com/?m=sent");

?>
```

The customer said that they are hosting their mail services with Gmail.
I am quite positive it has something to do with the suffix, but what can cause such a peculiar behavior?

Comment: If you `echo($to)` what value do you get?

Comment: `mail()` returns `TRUE` when it successfully passes the message to your outbound SMTP server. It does not and _cannot_ know what happens to the message after that.  The recipient domain might flat out refuse to accept mail from your server, rather than send to spam.

Comment: Thanks @Michael. But what can be the reason for that? What in my server definitions can make it unreliable or perceived as hazardous to the recipient domain?

Comment: that's like asking "my package was sent to mail but it was never received. what's the problem?". we can't really know, you'll need to start debugging - check MX records, check mail server logs...

Comment: @Matanya There are many many reasons.  If it is a shared host or service like EC2, sometimes those IPs get blacklisted by Spamhaus et al, some receiving servers don't like certain headers, some will validate that the `From` header's domain matches the domain of the server sending it (which yours may not since you take `From` from $_POST). It is impossible to say.